# NixOS + docker nginx + dnsmasq for local somethingsomething.dev domains

Tags: docker, nginx, dnsmasq, nixos, resolv.conf

I have been configuring NixOS as a dev machine lately (and so far I really love it). I was planning of using a nginx image as reverse proxy to route all *.dev requests to running docker images. This works for requests to localhost already, as I can reach apps of started conainers when they're connected to the same network.

Now for resolving *.dev requests I added a dnsmasq configuration to my nixos config:

```
services.dnsmasq = {
  enable = true;
  resolveLocalQueries = true;
  servers = [
    ''/.dev/127.0.0.1''
    ''8.8.8.8''
    ''8.8.4.4''
  ];
};
```

When rebuilding, I get the output `starting the following units: dnsmasq.service`, but when I try to reach my .dev URI's, I still only get `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN`. What could be the issue here?

Comment: Fun fact: the `.dev` TLD actually exists.

Comment: Thes following commands will provide useful info: `systemctl status dnsmasq`, `journalctl -u dnsmasq` `dig +trace domain.dev`